# How to compare key sequences from a large array, to find out the largest number of duplicate sequences?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have already compared the data of a matrix, I have already counted the data of an array, but I have never counted, what is the repeated sequence of keys between the arrays, I want to make comparative between all sequences, and find out the maximum size of this section Repeated .. I have many hundreds of numbers that I should compare them between them, and find out the largest duplicate stretch between them, the maximum duplicity size that exists in a sequence, and that also exist in another sequence of the large array!

Finding repeating single elements can simply be done with in_array(). Repeating keys from different arrays is similarly easy with array_keys(). Neither really helps us since we are concerned with sequences, not single values.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo 'test - This is just for us to figure out, what is the size of the greatest duplication of stretches between the previous sequences'.'<br>';


$previous_results_manually_inserted = array(
 array('12','21','34','1','51','87','42','49','37','119','101','7','111','17','11','19','2','15','6'),
 array('3','5','1','18','61','75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','71','17','08','51','37'),
 array('81',75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','17','65','44','73','27','30','41','74','88'),
);

foreach ( $previous_results_manually_inserted as $previous ) {

         $match = preg_match("/.*$test.*/", $previous );
}    

echo 'The largest repeated slice between these sequences is:'; 
echo implode(', ',  $match ), "<br>\n"
```

output:  75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2'

Note: Final objective: the highest duplicity is 9 numbers. (In this example)

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to find duplicates in `$previous_results_manually_inserted = array(
 array('12','21','34','1','51','87','42','49','37','119','101','7','111','17','11','19','2','15','6'),
 array('3','5','1','18','61','75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','71','17','08','51','37'),
 array('81',75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','17','65','44','73','27','30','41','74','88'),
);`

Comment: What is contained in `$test`? `preg_match` returns a boolean, it is nonsense to apply `implode` on it. `$match` is reinitialized in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is very similar to the algorithm for finding the largest common string. Can be solved as follows:

```
$arrs = [
 ['12','21','34','1','51','87','42','49','37','119','101','7','111','17','11','19','2','15','6'],
 ['3','5','1','18','61','75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','71','17','08','51','37'],
 ['81','75','92','84','36','81','2','07','90','2','17','65','44','73','27','30','41','74','88'],
];
$sequence = [];
foreach($arrs as $offset => $item){
    $sarr = array_slice($arrs , $offset+1);
    $count = count($item);
    foreach($sarr as $arr){
        $str = join(',',$arr);
        for($a = 0;$a<$count;$a++){
            for($b = 1;$b<$count;$b++){
                $needle = join(',',array_slice($item , $a , ($a + $b > $count ? $count : $b)));
                if(strpos($str,$needle) !== false){
                    $sequence[(substr_count($needle,','))] = $needle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo array_pop($sequence).PHP_EOL;

//out : 75,92,84,36,81,2,07,90,2
```